# I can't import tensorflow.lite.Interpreter for my Android Project even though i already added the dependencies

Tags: java, android, tensorflow

This is the ObjectDetectorClass im using

```
package com.example.mytranslator;
import android.content.res.AssetFileDescriptor;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;

import org.checkerframework.checker.units.qual.A;
import org.opencv.android.Utils;
import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.core.Point;
import org.opencv.core.Scalar;
import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;
import org.tensorflow.lite.Interpreter;
import org.tensorflow.lite.gpu.GpuDelegate;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class objectDetectorClass {
    // should start from small letter

    // this is used to load model and predict
    private Interpreter interpreter;
    // store all label in array
    private List<String> labelList;
    private int INPUT_SIZE;
    private int PIXEL_SIZE=3; // for RGB
    private int IMAGE_MEAN=0;
    private  float IMAGE_STD=255.0f;
    // use to initialize gpu in app
    private GpuDelegate gpuDelegate;
    private int height=0;
    private  int width=0;

    objectDetectorClass(AssetManager assetManager,String modelPath, String labelPath,int inputSize) throws IOException{
        INPUT_SIZE=inputSize;
        // use to define gpu or cpu // no. of threads
        Interpreter.Options options=new Interpreter.Options();
        gpuDelegate=new GpuDelegate();
        options.addDelegate(gpuDelegate);
        options.setNumThreads(4); // set it according to your phone
        // loading model
        interpreter=new Interpreter(loadModelFile(assetManager,modelPath),options);
        // load labelmap
        labelList=loadLabelList(assetManager,labelPath);


    }

    private List<String> loadLabelList(AssetManager assetManager, String labelPath) throws IOException {
        // to store label
        List<String> labelList=new ArrayList<>();
        // create a new reader
        BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(assetManager.open(labelPath)));
        String line;
        // loop through each line and store it to labelList
        while ((line=reader.readLine())!=null){
            labelList.add(line);
        }
        reader.close();
        return labelList;
    }

    private ByteBuffer loadModelFile(AssetManager assetManager, String modelPath) throws IOException {
        // use to get description of file
        AssetFileDescriptor fileDescriptor=assetManager.openFd(modelPath);
        FileInputStream inputStream=new FileInputStream(fileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor());
        FileChannel fileChannel=inputStream.getChannel();
        long startOffset =fileDescriptor.getStartOffset();
        long declaredLength=fileDescriptor.getDeclaredLength();

        return fileChannel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY,startOffset,declaredLength);
    }
    // create new Mat function
    public Mat recognizeImage(Mat mat_image){
        // Rotate original image by 90 degree get get portrait frame
        Mat rotated_mat_image=new Mat();
        Core.flip(mat_image.t(),rotated_mat_image,1);
        // if you do not do this process you will get improper prediction, less no. of object
        // now convert it to bitmap
        Bitmap bitmap=null;
        bitmap=Bitmap.createBitmap(rotated_mat_image.cols(),rotated_mat_image.rows(),Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Utils.matToBitmap(rotated_mat_image,bitmap);
        // define height and width
        height=bitmap.getHeight();
        width=bitmap.getWidth();

        // scale the bitmap to input size of model
        Bitmap scaledBitmap=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap,INPUT_SIZE,INPUT_SIZE,false);

        // convert bitmap to bytebuffer as model input should be in it
        ByteBuffer byteBuffer=convertBitmapToByteBuffer(scaledBitmap);

        // defining output
        // 10: top 10 object detected
        // 4: there coordinate in image
        //  float[][][]result=new float[1][10][4];
        Object[] input=new Object[1];
        input[0]=byteBuffer;

        Map<Integer,Object> output_map=new TreeMap<>();
        // we are not going to use this method of output
        // instead we create treemap of three array (boxes,score,classes)

        float[][][]boxes =new float[1][10][4];
        // 10: top 10 object detected
        // 4: there coordinate in image
        float[][] scores=new float[1][10];
        // stores scores of 10 object
        float[][] classes=new float[1][10];
        // stores class of object

        // add it to object_map;
        output_map.put(0,boxes);
        output_map.put(1,classes);
        output_map.put(2,scores);

        // now predict
        interpreter.runForMultipleInputsOutputs(input,output_map);
        // Before watching this video please watch my previous 2 video of
        //      1. Loading tensorflow lite model
        //      2. Predicting object
        // In this video we will draw boxes and label it with it's name

        Object value=output_map.get(0);
        Object Object_class=output_map.get(1);
        Object score=output_map.get(2);

        // loop through each object
        // as output has only 10 boxes
        for (int i=0;i<10;i++){
            float class_value=(float) Array.get(Array.get(Object_class,0),i);
            float score_value=(float) Array.get(Array.get(score,0),i);
            // define threshold for score
            if(score_value>0.5){
                Object box1=Array.get(Array.get(value,0),i);
                // we are multiplying it with Original height and width of frame

                float top=(float) Array.get(box1,0)*height;
                float left=(float) Array.get(box1,1)*width;
                float bottom=(float) Array.get(box1,2)*height;
                float right=(float) Array.get(box1,3)*width;
                // draw rectangle in Original frame //  starting point    // ending point of box  // color of box       thickness
                Imgproc.rectangle(rotated_mat_image,new Point(left,top),new Point(right,bottom),new Scalar(0, 255, 0, 255),2);
                // write text on frame
                // string of class name of object  // starting point                         // color of text           // size of text
                Imgproc.putText(rotated_mat_image,labelList.get((int) class_value),new Point(left,top),3,1,new Scalar(255, 0, 0, 255),2);
            }

        }
        // select device and run

        // before returning rotate back by -90 degree
        Core.flip(rotated_mat_image.t(),mat_image,0);
        return mat_image;
    }

    private ByteBuffer convertBitmapToByteBuffer(Bitmap bitmap) {
        ByteBuffer byteBuffer;
        // some model input should be quant=0  for some quant=1
        // for this quant=0

        int quant=0;
        int size_images=INPUT_SIZE;
        if(quant==0){
            byteBuffer=ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(1*size_images*size_images*3);
        }
        else {
            byteBuffer=ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(4*1*size_images*size_images*3);
        }
        byteBuffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        int[] intValues=new int[size_images*size_images];
        bitmap.getPixels(intValues,0,bitmap.getWidth(),0,0,bitmap.getWidth(),bitmap.getHeight());
        int pixel=0;

        // some error
        //now run
        for (int i=0;i<size_images;++i){
            for (int j=0;j<size_images;++j){
                final  int val=intValues[pixel++];
                if(quant==0){
                    byteBuffer.put((byte) ((val>>16)&0xFF));
                    byteBuffer.put((byte) ((val>>8)&0xFF));
                    byteBuffer.put((byte) (val&0xFF));
                }
                else {
                    // paste this
                    byteBuffer.putFloat((((val >> 16) & 0xFF))/255.0f);
                    byteBuffer.putFloat((((val >> 8) & 0xFF))/255.0f);
                    byteBuffer.putFloat((((val) & 0xFF))/255.0f);
                }
            }
        }
        return byteBuffer;
    }
}
// Next video is about drawing box and labeling it
// If you have any problem please inform me
```

While this is my app level build.gradle file

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.example.mytranslator'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.mytranslator"
        minSdk 24
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        applicationId "opencv.org"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            jni {
                srcDirs 'src\\main\\jni', 'src\\main\\jniLibs'
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation project(path: ':opencv')
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'

    implementation 'androidx.camera:camera-core:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.camera:camera-camera2:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.camera:camera-lifecycle:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.camera:camera-video:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.camera:camera-view:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.camera:camera-extensions:1.0.0'

    implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-task-vision:0.4.0'
    implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-gpu-delegate-plugin:0.4.0'
    implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-gpu:2.9.0'
    implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:0.0.0-nightly'
}
```

Im quite confused on how to setup interpreter

I tried some suggetions from similar questions but it seems to not work, i also read that its suggested to use InterpreterApi instead of Interpreter although im not sure since im pretty new myself.